# Will a processor socket with bent pins still work?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Will a processor socket with bent / broken off pins still work if the processor still sits in it ok? Purely hypothetical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pins are there for a reason so if any are missing or making poor contact then it's likely to cause some form of problem - permanent or intermittent.

Just for elaboration: you may get lucky if the broken pin/socket is a ground or power one as there's more than one of those, but the power and ground contacts are spread out to share the power load and to cut down on electrical noise so the CPU may still not work properly. If it's a broken data, address, timing or control contact then you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 5):

If any pins are broken off then the processor won't work - there'll be a missing connection. As with an electrical or data connection if it's not there then the processor can't work.

If any pins are bent, then as long as the processor still fits in the socket (i.e. the pins aren't bent *too* much) it should still work as there will be all the connections present.

Comment: It's like a leg.  Bent is ok.  Broken off is SOL.

Comment: FYI, I have used an [AMD FX-55](http://products.amd.com/pages/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=28) that had a broken pin with success. The lost pin (2nd from corner IIRC) was responsible for one of the RAM channels, so the PC would only boot with DIMMs in slot 1 & 3 and wouldn't POST with DIMMs in the other channel (slots 2 & 4). Not ideal as the missing RAM channel essentially caused a bottleneck - halving the speed of the computer. :)

Comment: I don't see how a bent pin is gonig to work. The lengths of the pins are such that they will contact the pads on the processor when the pins are straight. If a pin is bent it will not reach all the way to its corresponding pad. (If it would, then after normal installation of a CPU, all of the pins would be bent! )

Comment: @JamieHanrahan - if the pin is bent it's still the right length and will straighten when the processor is attached. The connection doesn't have to go along the whole length of the pin.

Comment: The OP asked "Will a processor socket with bent / broken off pins still work if the processor still sits in it ok?" That's describing an LGA-type socket. The pins don't go into anything. Their points just touch the "lands" on the CPU. If they're bent, they won't.